# Configuring Automatic Start of Azure Virtual Machine upon Remote Desktop Login

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, rdp, startup

We have created an Azure virtual machine 'Standard NV12ads A10 v5' with Windows 10 as the operating system. In order to reduce costs, we would like to find a way to have the machine powered on only when strictly necessary (ideally, when someone is connected via RDP). Currently, we automatically shut down the machine at a specific time, but we are looking for a solution that automatically powers on the machine as soon as someone connects via RDP. Additionally, the solution should be user-friendly as our users are not technical experts. What options are available to achieve this and minimize the impact on the users?